# Any idea on how to "slow down time" with an NSTimer?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I created a timer, and was wondering if it is at all possible to make the timer go slower when it reaches a certain second: `1..2..3..4..4.1..4.2`.

For example, the timer is increasing by `1` second, then at `4` seconds, the time slows down showing milliseconds.

```
if(i = 4) {

}
```

Comment: Once your timer reaches the last "normal" step (4 sec in your example), *replace* it with a new timer set to the new time interval.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want.
Of course, you can't slow down the time, but you can simulate it.
For example, you check how much time has already passed. If it is 1, 2, 3 seconds, you NSLog 1, 2, 3. Then when 4 seconds has passed, you start logging milliseconds.
E.g.

```
if (i < 4) {
NSLog(@"%d", i);
} else {
NSLog(@"4.%d", i - 4);
}
```

Sure, logging can be substituted with whatever you need.

P.S. The answer is in Objective-C, but that changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution like this:

Declare a `float` to register your `time` and a `NSTimer` to perform the action.

```
@property NSTimer *timer;
@property float time;
```

Call `startTimer` to start the actions.

```
- (void) startTimer {
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(secondsAction)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
}

- (void) secondsAction {
    self.time += 1;
    NSLog(@"%d", (int)self.time);

    if(self.time == 4) {
        [self.timer invalidate];

        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(milisecondsAction)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (void) milisecondsAction {
    self.time += 0.1;
    NSLog(@"%.1f", self.time);
}
```